# Add numbers of lists to the first number of the list

Tags: python, list, numpy, sum

I have the following list:

```
list_1 = [2.03898103, 2.23708741, 1.68221573, 1.12352885, 0.56227805]
```

And I want to add the numbers to the first number into the new list like this:

```
list_2 = []
list_2[0] = list_1[0]
list_2[1] = list_1[0] + list_1[1]
list_2[2] = list_1[0] + list_1[1] + list_1[2]
list_2[3] = list_1[0] + list_1[1] + list_1[2] + list_1[3]
list_2[4] = list_1[0] + list_1[1] + list_1[2] + list_1[3] + list_1[4]
```

How can I make this with a *for* loop or something more practical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
from itertools import accumulate

list_1 = [2.03898103, 2.23708741, 1.68221573, 1.12352885, 0.56227805]
list_2 = list(accumulate(list_1))
print(list_2)
```

Prints:

```
[2.03898103, 4.2760684399999995, 5.95828417, 7.08181302, 7.64409107]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you want a short answer, you can also use generators:

```
list_2 = [sum(list_1[:(i+1)]) for i in range(len(list_1))]
```

Comment: woow ! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
list_1 = [2.03898103, 2.23708741, 1.68221573, 1.12352885, 0.56227805]
list_2 = []
j = 0.
for i in range(0,len(list_1)):
    j = j + list_1[i]
    list_2.append(j)
print(list_2)
```

Comment: thank you, you solved for me another issue indirect. wow

Comment: @ZaidKhalil for a simpler approach, as this list is only formed by floats I would recomend using the cumsum() function from NumPy

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged as NumPy in your question, so just use `numpy.cumsum`:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> list_1 = np.array([2.03898103, 2.23708741, 1.68221573, 1.12352885, 0.56227805])
>>> np.cumsum(list_1)
array([2.03898103, 4.27606844, 5.95828417, 7.08181302, 7.64409107])
```

Comment: very nice i didn't know about that. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple *for* loops.

```
list_1 = [2.03898103, 2.23708741, 1.68221573, 1.12352885, 
0.56227805]
list_2 = []

for i in range(0, 4):
     for j in range(0, i):
          list_2[i] += list_1[j]
```

Comment: i tried a lot but i did mistakes. now i know my mistake. thx a lot

Comment: Yeah. Using multiple for loops is often an easy solution to problems that seeam complicated.